# Naive Bayes Probability Error Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have a Question, I have 2 dataset, AdultTest and AdultData. In these Dataset I have many Rows like this:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Female , 2174, 0, 40, United-States, >50K
```

And I want to calculate the probability of that a "Female" have ">50K", for that I did this:

```py
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

#Read AdultData.csv and encoded in Integer, so can I calculate the NaiveBAyes
data1 = np.genfromtxt('AdultData.csv', delimiter=',',  dtype='int', skip_footer=1)
datatest=np.genfromtxt('adultTest.csv', delimiter=',',  dtype='int', skip_footer=1)

#Delete the last Column, because the last column is the Target
data_new = np.delete(data1, 14, 1)
dataTest_new = np.delete(datatest, 14, 1)

class_ = [row[14] for row in data2]

clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(data_new, class_)
print(clf.predict_proba(dataTest_new))
```

And the result is the prediction of the probability, and I get always:

[1. 0.]

but I dont know why, even if I put the AdultTest(these have another Data) , I receive the same results.

Why I dont receive another results? Besides, why I have 2 Columns?

P.S. I do it because I want to do the massaging algorithmus for Classifying without Discriminating

Somebody could me help?

Thanks!

Comment: you have some mixup there. what is data2?

Comment: sorry, data2 is data1

Comment: Notice that you predict and train on the same data, meaning the score you get is a train score, not a test score (describing how well your model generalizes)

Comment: I think @ShaharA is right, so I posted an answer

Comment: but when I write : print(clf.predict_proba(datatest_new)) i Have the same result

Comment: you are predicting the prob of your data in your data, meaning 1 (for sure), you have to predict some point of your data and it will probably give you the chance of getting that value, or the chance of getting that value or something more extreme

Comment: E.serra, when I predict with another Data I receive the same result..

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a logical error in your code, as you never use `dataTest_new`

```
data_new = np.delete(data1, 14, 1)
dataTest_new = np.delete(datatest, 14, 1)

class_ = [row[14] for row in data2]

clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(data_new, class_)
# you should run prediction on test data
print(clf.predict_proba(dataTest_new))
```

Comment: I have the same result :/